# CarPlay app crashes when set root template - Unsupported object CPMapTemplate

Tags: ios, swift, carplay

I try to set root template as `CPTabBarTemplate` with `CPMapTemplate` and `CPListTemplate`. I get this message.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported object
> <CPMapTemplate: 0x600003712400> <identifier:
> FA0130C3-E609-4D78-94C4-1F88BBA9C181, userInfo: (null), tabTitle: Map,
> tabImage: (null), showsTabBadge: 0> passed to validateTemplates:.
> Allowed classes: {(
> CPInformationTemplate,
> CPPointOfInterestTemplate,
> CPGridTemplate,
> CPListTemplate )}'
> *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff80049b761 __exceptionPreprocess + 242  1   libobjc.A.dylib
> 0x00007ff800063904 objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
> 0x00007ff80049b63f -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 0  3   CarPlay
> 0x00007ff837772255 -[CPTabBarTemplate validateTemplates:] + 584   4
> CarPlay                             0x00007ff837771da8
> -[CPTabBarTemplate initWithTemplates:] + 88

The code is pretty straightforward:

```
        let mapTemplate = CPMapTemplate()
        mapTemplate.tabTitle = "Map"
        
        let listTemplate = CPListTemplate(title: "List", sections: [CPListSection(items: [CPListItem(text: "Title", detailText: "desctiption")])])
        listTemplate.tabTitle = "List"
        
        let tabBarTemplate = CPTabBarTemplate(templates: [mapTemplate, listTemplate])
        self.interfaceController?.setRootTemplate(tabBarTemplate, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But if I remove `CPMapTemplate`, I will see a tab bar template with a list template without any crashes.
What is the reason for that crash?

I use simulator iOS 17, Xcode 15.2, Intel, Entitlements key com.apple.developer.carplay-maps

Here is some inspiration of expected design

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message tells you exactly what the problem is. You can't add a `CPMapTemplate` to a `CPTabBarTemplate`:

> `Allowed classes: {( CPInformationTemplate, CPPointOfInterestTemplate, CPGridTemplate, CPListTemplate )}`

A `CPMapTemplate` can only be installed as the root template of your CarPlay app.

You will need to rethink the design of your app. For example, you could show the list modally in response to a button tap.

Based on the design you have shown, you probably want a EV charger "point of interest" CarPlay app.  This will let you use a `CPTabBarTemplate` containing `CPPointOfInterestatemplate`.

Comment: thanks, but I don't see this kind of restriction in apple documentation

Comment: I have just checked with `CPPointOfInterestTemplate ` instead of `CPMapTemplate` - there is another crash like " Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Application pushed an illegal template of class CPPointOfInterestTemplate'"

Comment: Some Apple documentation is better than others. CarPlay is one that isn't so great. It isn't stated explicitly in the documentation but it is shown clearly in the exception you get. Also, it wouldn't make sense to add a `CPMapTemplate` in a tab bar since this kind of template is rendered over the base layer that shows your map. See Apple's [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/carplay/integrating-carplay-with-your-navigation-app)

Comment: The point of interest template is only available if you have the parking, ev-charging or quick ordering CarPlay entitlement it isn't available with the maps entitlement.

Comment: thanks a lot!
I attached an expected design for out app. How can I implement that map with tab bar ?

Comment: Unfortunately CarPlay is much more limited in your layout choices than regular iOS development. You could use a trailing navigation button to switch the root template from the map to a tab bar view. The tab bar would then switch the root template back when the "map" tab was selected

Comment: Another design could have a `CPMapButton` that shows a mode selector or toggles through the three modes much like Apple's car play map does when you select the alert or orientation buttons.

Comment: Also, consider whether a CarPlay maps app is what you want to build. This kind of CarPlay app is responsible for drawing the base map and providing navigation routing directions. Google maps and Waze are examples of this kind of app. From your design you may be wanting to create a "point of interest" app where Apple renders the map for you.  It looks like you want the `ev-charging` entitlement

Comment: I also added 2 keys for parking and EV-charging to my Entitlement plist, but it is still crashing when add `CPPointOfInterestTemplate ` to tab bar templates.

Comment: Did you remove the maps entitlement ?

Comment: no,  I didn't remove maps entitlements

Comment: You should only have one CarPlay app type entitlement. Remove all but ev-charging